# thunderbird calendar background color: -> New event -> description

Tags: thunderbird

When creating a new event in Thunderbird's calendar the background color of the description field is almost black. This makes it almost impossible to read the text because it's black.
Field is in calendar --> new event --> tab "description" in the tab widget.

How can I change this background color?

I have found some HEX-values for colors in the configuration editor but not this one.

If relevant: Version 91.4.0, Fedora Linux (Wayland). I'm using the light theme.

Answer (score 3):

For those still struggling to find the correct and complete steps to change background color of "today" using Thunderbird updated release (May 2023) for Windows, when every single post on internet just shows incomplete or outdated things, here it is.

- Go to Tools -> Settings -> search "config ed", click "Config Editor" button.
- Search "legacyuser" -> it will show a row with "toolkit.legacyUserProfileCustomizations.stylesheets" -> double click so it turns the value to "TRUE".
- Help -> "More troubleshoot information" -> find "Profile Folder" (or you can press CTRL+F and type "profile") and then click "Open Folder" next to it.
- Create a folder "chrome" from that folder, and create a file "userChrome.css" inside.
- Add the following to that file. If already exists, just skip the "@namespace" row. Change the colors as you want. Mine for today is yellow:

> @namespace
> url("http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul");
>
> ```
> .calendar-month-day-box-current-month[selected="true"] {
>   background-color: orange !important;
> }
>
> .calendar-month-day-box-current-month[relation="today"] {
>   background-color: yellow !important;
> }
> ```

If it helped you, just upvote me.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely **due to a particular theme you have installed**; try either the Thunderbird default light or dark themes, instead.

However, you can control the colors of Calendar cells using Cascading Style Sheets (CSS), as follows:

- In the *Thunderbird *profile* folder, create a folder, *chrome*, if it does not exist.
- Using a test editor (e.g., *Kate*, *gedit*), create a file in the *Chrome* folder, userChrome.css, if it does not exist, or edit it.
- Add the following (if namespace is already in an existing file, do not add that line).

> @namespace url("http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul");
>
> /* Change color of Today & SelectedDay panes */
>
> .calendar-month-day-box-current-month[relation="today"] {background-color: #DDFFDD !important;}
>
> .calendar-month-day-box-current-month[selected="true"] {background-color: #FFFFAA !important;}

This changes the Calendar daily cell colors. It's not clear from your question if other parts need to change, such as the pop-up to edit an event. There are a number of answers to an online search for `thunderbird userChrome.css new event color` such as these about [Calendar & Today Pane](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1305077) and [How to change Event background color](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=46&t=2110127) that might help.